# Take a medicine or take a pill?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice

For some reason, *take a medicine* doesn't sound natural to my ears.

Is the phrase *take a medicine* wrong or unnatural?

I would usually say:

> take a pill

or

> take some medicine

What word would you use to emphasise that the pill is legitimate and medical?

More on the word **medicine**

Wiktionary and Online Oxford Dictionary seem to say that the word is countable. 
I thought I could use the word medicine as a group of things, pills, liquid, that you take to help you recover from an illness. So I thought it was a mass noun.

What does it mean if you say **a medicine**? 
I couldn't find a good example sentence. However, I could find some sentences that use the word in the plural form.

Is it only used in the plural form when it is used as a countable noun?

Comment: One way to indicate use of illegal pills, (or illegally acquired legal pills, or even a greater-than-prescribed number of pills) is **popping pills**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use both *medicine* and *pill* and both can mean that you are taking legitimate therapy. However, sometimes these terms are interchangeable, and sometimes not.

- Historically, a **[pill](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pill_%28pharmacy%29)** was a dosage form made manually, using the active substance, a sugar and a liquid binding agent :

> *small, round, solid pharmaceutical oral dosage form of medication that was **in use before the advent of tablets and capsules.** Pills were made by mixing the active ingredients with an excipient such as glucose syrup in a mortar and pestle to form a paste, then rolling the mass into a long cylindrical shape (called a "pipe"), and dividing it into equal portions, which were then rolled into balls, and often coated with sugar to make them more palatable.* (Wikipedia)

- **Today** a pill refers to all **oral solid dosage forms** that are intended to be swallowed as such (note that an [effervescent tablet](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effervescent_tablet) for example, most likely won't be referred to as a pill).
- **[The pill](http://www.merriam-webster.com/medical/pill)** or capitalized **The Pill** (definition 2) refers specifically to [birth control pills](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/birth+control+pill) (i.e. oral contraceptives).

In **everyday** (colloquial) **usage** to use the term pill meaning **medicine taken orally in a solid dosage form** is fine, but as a technical term it would be incorrect (unless of course you are making an exhibition about the history of pharmacy).

---

### But what if you are taking a medicine in a different dosage form?

You might need to take a syrup, an injection (insulin e.g.), use an inhaler etc. In this case pill doesn't work and you have to use the term **medicine** or use the term for a specific dosage form.

To take **a** medicine is used less often than to take a pill. But that doesn't mean that the word *medicine* is used less common in this sense than the word *pill*. Medicine is more often used in different constructions:

- Take this medicine:

> You need to take this medicine three times a day; this one you need to take twice a day.

- Take the medicine
- Take + personal pronoun + medicine:

> Make sure that the children take their medicine.

or

> *Kanga replied, “Roo, dear, you must take your medicine" [...]*
>
> *“I liked it better when Tigger ate my medicine for me,” said Roo.* (House at Pooh Corner, by A. A. Milne)

The word [medicine](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/medicine) can be both countable and uncountable, according to LDOCE.

This [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=take+a+pill%2Ctake+a+medicine%2Ctake+_PRON_+medicine%2Ctake+this+medicine%2Ctake+the+medicine%2Ctake+_PRON_+pill&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20pill%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20a%20medicine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20_PRON_%20medicine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20this%20medicine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20the%20medicine%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctake%20_PRON_%20pill%3B%2Cc0) shows that in fact, *medicine* (green) is used more often than *pill* (bright blue and dark red) except when they are used with the indefinite article:

[image]

---

A side note: medicines can also be administered and (especially for topical medicines) applied. (See more [in this post](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/54789/can-use-be-used-for-tips/54792#54792). You definitely don't eat a medicine, but this doesn't apply to Tiggers, because *"that's what they like best"*.